# How to close a datepicker on javascript when click somewhere outside the div?

Tags: javascript, function, html, datepicker

I downloaded a simple datepicker by Marc Grabanski. I want to add him a function, the thing is I don't know javascript.

I want to close the Calendar Div when I click somewhere outside, like if I pressed the close button.

**HTML:**

```
    <head>
        <script src="calendar.js"></script>
        <link href="calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="calendarDiv"></div>
        <h1>Modificado a partir do Original de <a href="http://marcgrabanski.com/">Marc Grabanski</a></h1>
        <br/>
        <label>Data:</label>
        <input type="text" class="calendarSelectDate"/>   
    </body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
/*!
 * Clean Calendar
 * Copyright 2007-2009 Marc Grabanski (m@marcgrabanski.com) http://marcgrabanski.com
 * Project Page: http://marcgrabanski.com/article/clean-calendar
 * Under the MIT License */

var popUpCal = {
  selectedMonth: new Date().getMonth(),
  // 0-11
  selectedYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
  // 4-digit year
  selectedDay: new Date().getDate(),
  calendarId: 'calendarDiv',
  inputClass: 'calendarSelectDate',

  init: function() {
    var x = getElementsByClass(popUpCal.inputClass, document, 'input');
    var y = document.getElementById(popUpCal.calendarId);
    // set the calendar position based on the input position
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].onfocus = function() {
        popUpCal.selectedMonth = new Date().getMonth();
        setPos(this, y);
        // setPos(targetObj,moveObj)
        y.style.display = 'block';
        popUpCal.drawCalendar(this);
        popUpCal.setupLinks(this);
      }
    }
  },

  drawCalendar: function(inputObj) {

    var html = '';
    html = '<a id="closeCalender"><img src="http://www.nzbmovieseeker.com/images/close.gif"></img></a>';
    html += '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="linksTable"><tr>';
    html += '   <td><a id="prevMonth"><b><< </b></a></td>';
    html += '<td colspan="7" class="calendarHeader">' + getMonthName(popUpCal.selectedMonth) + ' ' + popUpCal.selectedYear + '</td>';
    html += '   <td><a id="nextMonth"><b> >></b></a></td>';
    html += '</tr></table>';
    html += '<table id="calendar" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>';
    html += '</tr><tr class="weekDaysTitleRow">';
    var weekDays = new Array('D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S');
    for (var j = 0; j < weekDays.length; j++) {
      html += '<td>' + weekDays[j] + '</td>';
    }

    var daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(popUpCal.selectedYear, popUpCal.selectedMonth);
    var startDay = getFirstDayofMonth(popUpCal.selectedYear, popUpCal.selectedMonth);
    var numRows = 0;
    var printDate = 1;
    if (startDay != 7) {
      numRows = Math.ceil(((startDay + 1) + (daysInMonth)) / 7);
      // calculate the number of rows to generate
    }

    // calculate number of days before calendar starts
    if (startDay != 7) {
      var noPrintDays = startDay + 1;
    } else {
      var noPrintDays = 0;
      // if sunday print right away 
    }
    var today = new Date().getDate();
    var thisMonth = new Date().getMonth();
    var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    // create calendar rows
    for (var e = 0; e < numRows; e++) {
      html += '<tr class="weekDaysRow">';
      // create calendar days
      for (var f = 0; f < 7; f++) {
        if ((printDate == today)
        && (popUpCal.selectedYear == thisYear)
        && (popUpCal.selectedMonth == thisMonth)
        && (noPrintDays == 0)) {
          html += '<td id="today" class="weekDaysCell">';
        } else {
          html += '<td class="weekDaysCell">';
        }
        if (noPrintDays == 0) {
          if (printDate <= daysInMonth) {
            html += '<a>' + printDate + '</a>';
          }
          printDate++;
        }
        html += '</td>';
        if (noPrintDays > 0) noPrintDays--;
      }
      html += '</tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
    html += '<!--[if lte IE 6.5]><iframe src="javascript:false;" id="calendar_cover"></iframe><![endif]-->';

    // add calendar to element to calendar Div
    var calendarDiv = document.getElementById(popUpCal.calendarId);
    calendarDiv.innerHTML = html;

    // close button link
    document.getElementById('closeCalender').onclick = function() {
      calendarDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
    // setup next and previous links
    document.getElementById('prevMonth').onclick = function() {
      popUpCal.selectedMonth--;
      if (popUpCal.selectedMonth < 0) {
        popUpCal.selectedMonth = 11;
        popUpCal.selectedYear--;
      }
      popUpCal.drawCalendar(inputObj);
      popUpCal.setupLinks(inputObj);
    }
    document.getElementById('nextMonth').onclick = function() {
      popUpCal.selectedMonth++;
      if (popUpCal.selectedMonth > 11) {
        popUpCal.selectedMonth = 0;
        popUpCal.selectedYear++;
      }
      popUpCal.drawCalendar(inputObj);
      popUpCal.setupLinks(inputObj);
    }

  },
  // end drawCalendar function
  setupLinks: function(inputObj) {
    // set up link events on calendar table
    var y = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var x = y.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].onmouseover = function() {
        this.parentNode.className = 'weekDaysCellOver';
      }
      x[i].onmouseout = function() {
        this.parentNode.className = 'weekDaysCell';
      }
      x[i].onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById(popUpCal.calendarId).style.display = 'none';
        popUpCal.selectedDay = this.innerHTML;
        inputObj.value = formatDate(popUpCal.selectedDay, popUpCal.selectedMonth, popUpCal.selectedYear);
      }
    }
  }

}
// Add calendar event that has wide browser support
if (typeof window.addEventListener != "undefined")
 window.addEventListener("load", popUpCal.init, false);
else if (typeof window.attachEvent != "undefined")
 window.attachEvent("onload", popUpCal.init);
else {
  if (window.onload != null) {
    var oldOnload = window.onload;
    window.onload = function(e) {
      oldOnload(e);
      popUpCal.init();
    };
  }
  else
  window.onload = popUpCal.init;
}

/* Functions Dealing with Dates */

function formatDate(Day, Month, Year) {
  Month++;
  // adjust javascript month
  if (Month < 10) Month = '0' + Month;
  // add a zero if less than 10
  if (Day < 10) Day = '0' + Day;
  // add a zero if less than 10
  var dateString = Year + '-' + Month + '-' + Day;
  return dateString;
}

function getMonthName(month) {
  var monthNames = new Array('Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');
  return monthNames[month];
}

function getDayName(day) {
  var dayNames = new Array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')
  return dayNames[day];
}

function getDaysInMonth(year, month) {
  return 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();
}

function getFirstDayofMonth(year, month) {
  var day;
  day = new Date(year, month, 0).getDay();
  return day;
}

/* Common Scripts */

function getElementsByClass(searchClass, node, tag) {
  var classElements = new Array();
  if (node == null) node = document;
  if (tag == null) tag = '*';
  var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  var elsLen = els.length;
  var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\s)" + searchClass + "(\s|$)");
  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
    if (pattern.test(els[i].className)) {
      classElements[j] = els[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  return classElements;
}

/* Position Functions */

function setPos(targetObj, moveObj) {
  var coors = findPos(targetObj);
  moveObj.style.position = 'absolute';
  moveObj.style.top = coors[1] + 18 + 'px';
  moveObj.style.left = coors[0] + 'px';
}

function findPos(obj) {
  var curleft = curtop = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    curleft = obj.offsetLeft
    curtop = obj.offsetTop
    while (obj = obj.offsetParent) {
      curleft += obj.offsetLeft
      curtop += obj.offsetTop
    }
  }
  return [curleft, curtop];
}
```

Or JSFDDILE example: http://jsfiddle.net/CJEC8/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div that lies on top of the entire page, except the date picker itself. When you click the div, you close the datepicker (and remove the div, of course).

Comment: How do I do that? Can you help please?

Comment: If I do like you said, when I click on the textbox it will blikn and disappear. Maybe the event could be onblur of textbox?

Answer (score 0):

With a simple research I think i soulve your problem.

Paste this code before the method to close when you click in the button (before: `// close button link`
)

```
// Close when loses focus.
var divEls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var i = 0;
for(i=0;i<divEls.length;i++)
    document.getElementById(divEls[i].id).onblur = function() {
    calendarDiv.style.display = 'none';                 
}
```

Man, JsFiddle is so good. 
Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your question

```
var popUpCal = {
    selectedMonth: new Date().getMonth(),
    // 0-11
    selectedYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
    // 4-digit year
    selectedDay: new Date().getDate(),
    calendarId: 'calendarDiv',
    inputClass: 'calendarSelectDate',

    init: function() {
        var x = getElementsByClass(popUpCal.inputClass, document, 'input');
        var y = document.getElementById(popUpCal.calendarId);
        // set the calendar position based on the input position
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].onfocus=function() {
                popUpCal.selectedMonth = new Date().getMonth();
                setPos(this, y);
                // setPos(targetObj,moveObj)
                y.style.display = 'block';
                popUpCal.drawCalendar(this);
                popUpCal.setupLinks(this);
            }
            x[i].onblur=function(){
                popUpCal.hideCalendar();
            }
        }
    },

    drawCalendar: function(inputObj){
        var html = '';
        html = '<a id="closeCalender"><img src="http://www.nzbmovieseeker.com/images/close.gif"></img></a>';
        html += '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="linksTable"><tr>';
        html += '    <td><a id="prevMonth"><b><< </b></a></td>';
        html += '<td colspan="7" class="calendarHeader">' + getMonthName(popUpCal.selectedMonth) + ' ' + popUpCal.selectedYear + '</td>';
        html += '    <td><a id="nextMonth"><b> >></b></a></td>';
        html += '</tr></table>';
        html += '<table id="calendar" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>';
        html += '</tr><tr class="weekDaysTitleRow">';
        var weekDays = new Array('D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S');
        for (var j = 0; j < weekDays.length; j++) {
            html += '<td>' + weekDays[j] + '</td>';
        }

        var daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(popUpCal.selectedYear, popUpCal.selectedMonth);
        var startDay = getFirstDayofMonth(popUpCal.selectedYear, popUpCal.selectedMonth);
        var numRows = 0;
        var printDate = 1;
        if (startDay != 7) {
            numRows = Math.ceil(((startDay + 1) + (daysInMonth)) / 7);
            // calculate the number of rows to generate
        }

        // calculate number of days before calendar starts
        if (startDay != 7) {
            var noPrintDays = startDay + 1;
        } else {
            var noPrintDays = 0;
            // if sunday print right away    
        }
        var today = new Date().getDate();
        var thisMonth = new Date().getMonth();
        var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        // create calendar rows
        for (var e = 0; e < numRows; e++) {
            html += '<tr class="weekDaysRow">';
            // create calendar days
            for (var f = 0; f < 7; f++) {
                if ((printDate == today) && (popUpCal.selectedYear == thisYear) && (popUpCal.selectedMonth == thisMonth) && (noPrintDays == 0)) {
                    html += '<td id="today" class="weekDaysCell">';
                } else {
                    html += '<td class="weekDaysCell">';
                }
                if (noPrintDays == 0) {
                    if (printDate <= daysInMonth) {
                        html += '<a>' + printDate + '</a>';
                    }
                    printDate++;
                }
                html += '</td>';
                if (noPrintDays > 0) noPrintDays--;
            }
            html += '</tr>';
        }
        html += '</table>';
        html += '<!--[if lte IE 6.5]><iframe src="javascript:false;" id="calendar_cover"></iframe><![endif]-->';

        // add calendar to element to calendar Div
        var calendarDiv = document.getElementById(popUpCal.calendarId);
        calendarDiv.innerHTML = html;

        // close button link
        document.getElementById('closeCalender').onclick = function() {
            calendarDiv.style.display = 'none';
        }
        // setup next and previous links
        document.getElementById('prevMonth').onclick = function() {
            popUpCal.selectedMonth--;
            if (popUpCal.selectedMonth < 0) {
                popUpCal.selectedMonth = 11;
                popUpCal.selectedYear--;
            }
            popUpCal.drawCalendar(inputObj);
            popUpCal.setupLinks(inputObj);
        }
        document.getElementById('nextMonth').onclick = function() {
            popUpCal.selectedMonth++;
            if (popUpCal.selectedMonth > 11) {
                popUpCal.selectedMonth = 0;
                popUpCal.selectedYear++;
            }
            popUpCal.drawCalendar(inputObj);
            popUpCal.setupLinks(inputObj);
        }

    },
    hideCalendar:function(){
        var calendarDiv=document.getElementById(popUpCal.calendarId);
        calendarDiv.style.display = 'none';
    },
    // end drawCalendar function
    setupLinks: function(inputObj) {
        // set up link events on calendar table
        var y = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var x = y.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].onmouseover = function() {
                this.parentNode.className = 'weekDaysCellOver';
            }
            x[i].onmouseout = function() {
                this.parentNode.className = 'weekDaysCell';
            }
            x[i].onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById(popUpCal.calendarId).style.display = 'none';
                popUpCal.selectedDay = this.innerHTML;
                inputObj.value = formatDate(popUpCal.selectedDay, popUpCal.selectedMonth, popUpCal.selectedYear);
            }
        }
    }

}
// Add calendar event that has wide browser support
if (typeof window.addEventListener != "undefined") window.addEventListener("load", popUpCal.init, false);
else if (typeof window.attachEvent != "undefined") window.attachEvent("onload", popUpCal.init);
else {
    if (window.onload != null) {
        var oldOnload = window.onload;
        window.onload = function(e) {
            oldOnload(e);
            popUpCal.init();
        };
    }
    else window.onload = popUpCal.init;
}

/* Functions Dealing with Dates */

function formatDate(Day, Month, Year) {
    Month++;
    // adjust javascript month
    if (Month < 10) Month = '0' + Month;
    // add a zero if less than 10
    if (Day < 10) Day = '0' + Day;
    // add a zero if less than 10
    var dateString = Year + '-' + Month + '-' + Day;
    return dateString;
}

function getMonthName(month) {
    var monthNames = new Array('Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');
    return monthNames[month];
}

function getDayName(day) {
    var dayNames = new Array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')
    return dayNames[day];
}

function getDaysInMonth(year, month) {
    return 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();
}

function getFirstDayofMonth(year, month) {
    var day;
    day = new Date(year, month, 0).getDay();
    return day;
}

/* Common Scripts */

function getElementsByClass(searchClass, node, tag) {
    var classElements = new Array();
    if (node == null) node = document;
    if (tag == null) tag = '*';
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var elsLen = els.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\s)" + searchClass + "(\s|$)");
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
        if (pattern.test(els[i].className)) {
            classElements[j] = els[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return classElements;
}

/* Position Functions */

function setPos(targetObj, moveObj) {
    var coors = findPos(targetObj);
    moveObj.style.position = 'absolute';
    moveObj.style.top = coors[1] + 18 + 'px';
    moveObj.style.left = coors[0] + 'px';
}

function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        curleft = obj.offsetLeft
        curtop = obj.offsetTop
        while (obj = obj.offsetParent) {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft
            curtop += obj.offsetTop
        }
    }
    return [curleft, curtop];
}
```

I have added the

```
    x[i].onblur=function(){
        popUpCal.hideCalendar();
    }
```

In the init function
And a new function hideCalendar after the //end drawCalendar function

```
// end drawCalendar function
    hideCalendar:function(){
        var calendarDiv=document.getElementById(popUpCal.calendarId);
        calendarDiv.style.display = 'none';
    },
```

Please keep in mind, that this is a simple fix. I would recommend using another lib for this. You can try jQuery or one of the many other datepickers out there..

--Cheers, Ex

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

html

```
<div id="closeCalendar"></div>
```

css

```
#closeCalendar {display:none;position:fixed; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%; z-index:100;}
#calendarDiv {z-index: 200;}
```

js

```
document.getElementById('closeCalendar').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('calendarDiv').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('closeCalendar').style.display = 'none';
}

...
init:
...
document.getElementById('closeCalendar').style.display = 'block';
...
```